# Prove that these result are the same

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I did this trigonometric integral in two different ways, and the results that I got were with two different trigonometric functions, $\sec x$ and $\tan x$.

The integral is:
$\mathbf{\int tan^{5}x \, \, \,  sec^{4}x \; \; dx} \\ $

**Result 1:**
$\frac{\tan^{8}x}{8} + \frac{\tan^{6}x}{6} + C \\$

**Result 2:**
$\frac{\sec^{8}x}{8} + \frac{1}{3} \sec^{6}x + \frac{\sec^{4}x}{4} + C$

My questions is: ¿How do I prove that these results are the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Differentiating both expressions will work.

Comment: You can also use $\sec^2x = 1 + \tan^2 x$ without taking the derivative, but it looks to be pretty tedious